# Using the Minkowski bound to prove that a ring is principal

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains, ideal-class-group

Let $\alpha  =e^{2i\pi/7}$. Prove that $\Bbb Z[\alpha  ]$ is principal.

I try to prove that the class group of $\Bbb K:=\Bbb Q[\alpha  ]$ is trivial which I think is sufficient condition to prove that $\mathcal O_K$ is principal.

The Minkowski bound computed on Sage is $M_k=4.12$ for $n:=[K:\Bbb Q]=6, r_1=0, r_2=3$.

We need to check the prime ideals of $\mathcal O_K$ lying above $(2)$ and $(3)$.

Let $f(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha  $ over $\Bbb Q$.

since $x\equiv x^2\equiv x^3\equiv x^4\equiv x^6 (mod\ 2)$, reducing $f$ mod 2 we get:

$f_2(x)\equiv 1+x^3+x^5=1+x(x^2+x^4)\equiv 1\ (mod\ 2)$

Hence $2\mathcal O_K=(2,1)=(1)$

I am not sure how to interpret this result. I think that something is wrong since in sage I get a different result:

$ (Fractional\ ideal (\alpha  ^3 + \alpha   + 1)) * (Fractional\ ideal (-\alpha  ^5 - \alpha  ^3 - \alpha  ^2 - \alpha  ))$.

Moving on with factoring $(3)$

$x\equiv x^3\equiv x^5 (mod\ 3) \Rightarrow f_3(x)\equiv 1+x^2+x^6=1-2x^2-2x^6$ which is irreducible by Eisenstein at the prime $2$.

Hence in $3\mathcal O_K=(3,1+\alpha  ^2+\alpha  ^6)$ is prime

So Since $(2)$ and $(3)$ are also prime in $\mathcal O_K$ so the ideal classes $[2]$ and $[3]$ generate the class group. But since the representatives $(2)$ and $(3)$ are are principal, they both belong to the trivial ideal class, Hence $\mathcal O_K$ is principal.

Is this correct? Thank your for any help

Comment: The congruences you are using to simplify $f$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$ only hold for elements of $\mathbb{F}_2$, they are not polynomial identities.

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you. So if I understand I should only reduce mod p the coefficient of the polynomials?

Comment: Yes, that’s it. Note also that the splitting field of $X^7-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ is $\mathbb{F}_8$, and that any root but $1$ generates the field above, so there are two factors of degree $3$ to $X^6+X^5+X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: Thank you! Now that $2\mathcal O_K = \mathcal p_2 \mathcal p'_2$ should prove that  prove that $\mathcal p_2=(2,1+\alpha  +\alpha  ^3)$ and $\mathcal p'_2=(2,-\alpha^5  -\alpha  ^3-\alpha^2  -\alpha )$ are both principal? I have no clue on how to proceed?

Comment: Note that $(1+\alpha+\alpha^3)(1+\alpha^4+\alpha^6)=1+\alpha+\alpha^3+\alpha^4+\alpha^5+1+\alpha^6+1+\alpha^2=2$...